# How to convert Android app to Chrome app?

Tags: android, google-chrome, apk, manifest, store

I'm trying to convert my app to Chrome app, so i can publish it on Chrome Web Store.
I used ARChon Packager to obtain a folder to load in Google Chrome, but it creates a not-working app, in fact when i try to load in extensions it says that manifest file is missing or unreadable. I solve this problem adding the following line

```
"message": "App"
```

in messages.json file (_locales/en folder), under `description` field in `extName`.
Anyway it doesn't work, nothing happens when i try to load it with **Load unpacked extension** button.

So i tried this [tutorial](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-run-android-apps-inside-chrome-on-any-desktop-op-1637564101) (both chrome-apk tool and manually way) but it results in the same behaviour: nothing happens when i load it in Google Chrome extensions.

What could be the problem?
I'm using the latest version of Google Chrome: 38.0.2125.104 (64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

Each Chrome app and Chrome extension need the **manifest.json** file in the root of the project folder. Check if you have this file there
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest

Comment: I want to convert the app and publish it to Chrome Web Store. Can i do that?

Comment: What is the language of your code project? HTML5 is only allowed in the Chrome web store.